Estimate for smallest "total non-residue"
Let $P(x) = \{3 \leq p \leq x\}$ be the set of odd primes up to $x$. For each odd prime $p$, let $T(p)$ be the set of non square-residues modulo $p$, so that $|T(p)| = (p-1)/2$. Define
$$\displaystyle N(x) = \min \{n \in \mathbb{N} : n \pmod{p} \in T(p) \text{ for all } p \in P(x), n  \equiv 3,5,7 \pmod{8}\}.$$
In other words, $N(x)$ is the smallest odd positive integer which is not congruent to a square modulo $p$ for every odd prime $p \leq x$, and $N(x)$ is not a square modulo $8$.
Is there an explicit lower bound for $N(x)$, at least for some sufficiently large $x$ (the largeness also made explicit)?

There is a lot of literature on the smallest nonsquare that is a square modulo $p$ for every odd prime $p\le x$; the relevant search term is "pseudosquare". I don't know if there is much literature on the smallest quadratic nonresidue, but it is discussed as Problem VI in Lehmer, Lehmer, and Shanks, Integer sequences having prescribed quadratic character, Math Comp 24 (1970) #110 433-451, available at https://oeis.org/A002189/a002189.pdf

According to Eric Bach, Explicit bounds for primality testing and related problems, assuming ERH there is always a quadratic non-residue up to $2(\log n)^2$, which might be helpful
